# What is the font used in this Crane Towing Logo?

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to redo this logo in Illustrator. There is no larger image size than what I've found and I can't use live trace on it. So I'm redo-ing it with the pen tool and was just wondering what's the font used in this logo:

[image: Crane Towing logo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font name is ITC Eras Bold

by Albert Boton

[image]

Distribution type:  Commercial
Font distributor:   Fonts.com

You can buy the font from here :

[ITC Eras® Bold](http://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/itc-eras/bold)